# Django template tags for changing key names in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

I'm working on a kanji website with Django templates. I have a dictionaries made out of an external xml. I set xml tags as keys. Here is an example of one of those dicitionaries (which casually happens to be about dictionaries... paper ones :P)

```
'dictionaryEntries': {'nelson_c': '43', 'nelson_n': '81', 'halpern_njecd': '3540', 'halpern_kkd': '4354', 
'halpern_kkld': '2204', 'halpern_kkld_2ed': '2966', 'heisig': '1809', 'heisig6': '1950', 'gakken': '1331', 'oneill_names': '525', 'oneill_kk': '1788', 'moro': '272', 'henshall': '997', 'sh_kk': '1616', 'sh_kk2': '1724', 'jf_cards': '1032', 'tutt_cards': '1092', 'kanji_in_context': '1818', 'kodansha_compact': '35', 'maniette': '1827'}
```

Using the following code on template, they are displayed on the website:

```
<ul>
        {% for key, value in dictionaryEntries.items %}
        <li><b>{{key}}: </b>{{value}}</li>
        {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

And they get something like following on html:

```
<ul>
        
        <li><b>nelson_c: </b>2991</li>
        
        <li><b>nelson_n: </b>3715</li>
        
        <li><b>halpern_njecd: </b>3497</li>
        
        <li><b>halpern_kkd: </b>4309</li>
        
        <li><b>halpern_kkld: </b>2179</li>
        
        <li><b>halpern_kkld_2ed: </b>2933</li>
        
        <li><b>heisig: </b>1555</li>
        
        <li><b>heisig6: </b>1675</li>
        
        <li><b>gakken: </b>29</li>
        
        <li><b>oneill_names: </b>214</li>
        
        <li><b>oneill_kk: </b>67</li>
        
        <li><b>moro: </b>21670</li>
        
        <li><b>henshall: </b>42</li>
        
        <li><b>sh_kk: </b>44</li>
        
        <li><b>sh_kk2: </b>44</li>
        
        <li><b>sakade: </b>34</li>
        
        <li><b>jf_cards: </b>71</li>
        
        <li><b>henshall3: </b>44</li>
        
        <li><b>tutt_cards: </b>43</li>
        
        <li><b>crowley: </b>9</li>
        
        <li><b>kanji_in_context: </b>49</li>
        
        <li><b>busy_people: </b>2.4</li>
        
        <li><b>kodansha_compact: </b>1327</li>
        
        <li><b>maniette: </b>1569</li>
        
    </ul>
```

However, as you can see, key values such as `nelson_c` are not very user-friendly. I don't want to change the tag name on xml. Is there a way, maybe via tags, to change those computer like keys to a more user-friednly text (in `nelson_c` case, it shuld be "Nelson Classic").

Thank you in advance for all your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. With a simple conditional it works.

```
{%if key == "nelson_c" %}
                <li><b>Classic Nelson: </b>{{value}}</li>
```